# Interface type checking props not working in React Typescript app

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I created an app a few months ago with `create-react-app` with the basic command `npx create-react-app my-app`

Then, I separately installed typesctip in the project and created a tsconfig.json and finally renamed `App.js` to `App.tsx` and used `*.tsx` in all my following components.

However, I have been noticing that the type checking of the props on my components is not working. It's like the props are always `any`. This is how I do:

```
interface IReportProps {
  title: string;
  data: IReportData[];
}

export const Report: FC<IReportProps> = ({ title, data }) => {
...
```

So, I import the `FC` interface from the react package and merge it with component props. But, `title` and `data` are of type `any`.

Later, I found out that creating the react app with the flag `yarn create react-app my-app --template typescript` already adds typesctipt to the project and the way I use the props (shown above) works perfectly there. But I didnt want to recreate the whole app.

Is there any way I can make it work in my current version?

My eslint.json:

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "plugin:import/typescript",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "airbnb"
  ],
  "globals": {
    "Atomics": "readonly",
    "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
  },
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "project": "./tsconfig.json",
    "createDefaultProgram": true,
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 11,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"]
      }
    },
    "react": {
      "version": "detect"
    }
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react",
    "react-hooks",
    "@typescript-eslint",
    "import-helpers"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": "off",
    "import/prefer-default-export": "off",
    "lines-between-class-members": "off",
    "react/prop-types": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/interface-name-prefix": [
      "error",
      {
        "prefixWithI": "always"
      }
    ],
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"] }],
    "import/extensions": [
      "error",
      "ignorePackages",
      {
        "js": "never",
        "jsx": "never",
        "ts": "never",
        "tsx": "never"
      }
    ],
    "import-helpers/order-imports": [
      "warn",
      {
        "newlinesBetween": "always", // new line between groups
        "groups": [
          "/^react/",
          "/^mobx/",
          "module",
          [
            "parent",
            "sibling",
            "index"
          ]
        ],
        "alphabetize": {
          "order": "asc",
          "ignoreCase": true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "types": [],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "cypress"
  ],
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I think re-creating an app is the cleanest way to go about it.

Comment: @JanezKuhar what about maintaning my current react version?

Comment: What do you loose by upgrading to the latest, as generated by the `create-creact-app` script?

Comment: @JanezKuhar Yeah, indeed. I recreated the app with the template flag and moved my code there. It's working as expected now. Thanks a lot